# Python - send image data through http post - expected str instance, bytes found

Tags: python, image, post

Please, help. I'm upgrading code from Python2 to Python3

Need to load image:

```
image = open("image.jpg", "rb").read()
```

and then send through http POST:

```
BOUNDARY = '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$'
CRLF = '\r\n'
L = []
L.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
L.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="s"; filename="%s"' % (file_name))
L.append('Content-Type: %s' % mime_type)
L.append('')
L.append(image)
L.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
L.append('')
body = CRLF.join(L)

http1 = http.client.HTTPSConnection(REMOTE_HOST)
data = ''
http1.connect()
http1.putrequest("POST", UPLOAD_URL)
http1.putheader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY)
http1.putheader('Content-length', str(len(body)))
http1.endheaders()
http1.send(body)

r = http1.getresponse()
```

But I get error "expected str instance, bytes found". How can I change bytes to str right?
I tried many ways but without success:

*str(image), image.decode(...) ....*

Many thanks

Comment: If the code isn't too complicated I would recommend using ```requests``` module for python3. ```http.client``` It is normally not used directly — the module ```urllib.request``` uses it to handle URLs that use HTTP and HTTPS. (source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html)

Comment: I'm afraid the error is on the line "body = CRLF.join(L)"  , that is, before post sending